# How to adapt an old Canon lens to Sony E mount?

Tags: lens-adapter, old-lenses

I just got a Sony a5100.
It has a E mount lens.

My mom has an old lens with an A on it. It's attached to a old Canon camera.

Is there an adapter for this?

Comment: Unless we know exactly what lens is on the old Canon, it is difficult to say. Canon had multiple lens mounts in the past. Be aware that there is also an A-mount for Sony, which has nothing to do with the lens you are looking at.

Comment: By the way, none of Canon's mounts is designated "A". They are: FL, FD, EF, EF-S, EF-M, RF (oldest to newest)

Comment: What else is written on the lens? Is "A" the only text anywhere??

Answer (score 2):

The “A” you see is probably just the Auto Setting on the aperture ring of the lens. The lens is most likely a Canon FD lens from a Canon film camera. If it is an FD lens, it can be used on your Sony camera with a simple FD to NEX mount adapter. The Sony a5100 will take nice photos with it if you don’t mind using manual aperture control and a manual focus.

[image]

[image]